# Update Minute and Seconds value in Dataframe column using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have DF as follows:

```
Name    starttime               endtime
user1   2019-08-02 03:34:45   2019-08-02 03:52:03
user2   2019-08-13 13:34:10   2019-08-13 14:02:10
```

I would like to check if the `endtime` bleeds into the next hour and if it does then update it to the last minute and second of the current hour as shown below.

```
Name    starttime               endtime
user1   2019-08-02 03:34:45   2019-08-02 03:52:03
user2   2019-08-13 13:34:10   2019-08-13 13:59:59
```

I can do the check & replace it as below using UDF but would prefer not to use them.

```
def adjust_end_hour(date):
    return date.replace(second=59,minute=59)

adjust_end_hour_udf = udf(adjust_end_hour, TimestampType())

df = df.\
   filter(df.endtime > adjust_end_hour_udf(df.starttime)).\
   withColumn('enddtime', adjust_end_hour_udf(df.starttime))
```

How can I do that without using UDF in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to truncate the `starttime` to hour then add 59 seconds and 59 minutes using SQL syntax `INTERVAL` like this:

```
adjust_expr = "date_trunc('hour', starttime) + INTERVAL 59 seconds + INTERVAL 59 minutes"

df.withColumn("endtime",
              when(col("endtime") > expr(adjust_expr),
                   expr(adjust_expr)
                  ).otherwise(col("endtime"))
              )\
  .show()
```

Gives:

```
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| name|          starttime|            endtime|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|user1|2019-08-02 03:34:45|2019-08-02 03:52:03|
|user2|2019-08-13 13:34:10|2019-08-13 13:59:59|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You could probably also use `pyspark.sql.functions.min` instead of `when`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame has the following schema:

```
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- starttime: timestamp (nullable = true)
# |-- endtime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

i.e. where `starttime` and `endtime` are both [`TimestampType()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType).

You can check if the `endtime` bleeds into the next hour by comparing the [`hour`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.hour) parts of `starttime` and `endtime`. If they are not equal<sup>1</sup>, that means you need to truncate the end time.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, hour

df.withColumn(
    "bleeds_into_next_hour", 
    hour(col("endtime")) != hour(col("starttime"))
).show()
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
#| Name|          starttime|            endtime|bleeds_into_next_hour|
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
#|user1|2019-08-02 03:34:45|2019-08-02 03:52:03|                false|
#|user2|2019-08-13 13:34:10|2019-08-13 14:02:10|                 true|
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

This tells you which rows need to be modified. You can almost get to the desired ouput using [`date_trunc`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc) with the `format` parameter set to `hour`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, when

df.withColumn(
    "bleeds_into_next_hour", 
    hour(col("endtime")) != hour(col("starttime"))
).withColumn(
    "endtime", 
    when(
        col("bleeds_into_next_hour"), 
        date_trunc('hour', "endtime")
    ).otherwise(col("endtime"))
).show()
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
#| Name|          starttime|            endtime|bleeds_into_next_hour|
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
#|user1|2019-08-02 03:34:45|2019-08-02 03:52:03|                false|
#|user2|2019-08-13 13:34:10|2019-08-13 14:00:00|                 true|
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

All you have to now is subtract 1 second from `endtime`. The easiest way is to convert a [`unix_timestamp`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp), subtract 1, and then convert back using [`from_unixtime`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp

df.withColumn(
    "bleeds_into_next_hour", 
    hour(col("endtime")) != hour(col("starttime"))
).withColumn(
    "endtime", 
    from_unixtime(
        unix_timestamp(
            when(
                col("bleeds_into_next_hour"), 
                date_trunc('hour', "endtime")
            ).otherwise(col("endtime"))
        ) - 1
    )
).drop("bleeds_into_next_hour").show()
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
#| Name|          starttime|            endtime|
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
#|user1|2019-08-02 03:34:45|2019-08-02 03:52:02|
#|user2|2019-08-13 13:34:10|2019-08-13 13:59:59|
#+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

---

Putting it all together, without the intermediary column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, date_trunc, from_unixtime, hour, unix_timestamp, when

df = df.withColumn(
    "endtime", 
    from_unixtime(
        unix_timestamp(
            when(
                hour(col("endtime")) != hour(col("starttime")), 
                date_trunc('hour', "endtime")
            ).otherwise(col("endtime"))
        ) - 1
    )
)
```

**Notes**

1. Assuming `endtime` is always greater than or equal to `starttime`. You can't do `>` because hours wrap after hour 12.

Comment: Thanks @pault. Fortunately, I have datetime in military format so good with checking > for datetime.